# How to find two words in the subject line of email in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, string

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim strSubject As String
  strSubject = Item.Subject
     If (Trim(strSubject)) Like "FOR REVIEW*" Then
         Prompt$ = "Please do xyz"
       If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Review Subject Line") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

1. Need to find FOR REVIEW anywhere in the subject .

   note: * FOR REVIEW * doesn't works !!
2. Need to change the button NO to 'Go back'.
   replacing No with Goback didn't work !!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? Tell us what are you expecting and what occurs that you didn't expect. Perhaps add examples of `strSubject` that don't work.

Comment: By doesn't work  i meant it doesn't finds the FOR REVIEW in the subject line. It would find only stuff after the word REVIEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
strSubject = Item.Subject
     If (Trim(strSubject)) Like "FOR REVIEW*" Then
```

To

```
Item.Subject LIKE "*For Review*"
```

So it finds the words.I removed TRIM function.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  "*" "FOR REVIEW" "*"
```

instead of

```
"FOR REVIEW*"
```